# index.css:undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am attempting the [Introducing a complete toolchain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools/Introducing_complete_toolchain) chapter of the [Understanding client-side web development tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools) module of the [MDN Front End Developer course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Front-end_web_developer). I have reached the final **Running the transformation** section where the instructions advise to run `npx parcel src/index.html`. At this stage I encounter two issues.

- The *build* process gets stuck on `Building scheduler-tracing.development.js`. After several aborted attempts I let this run for 6 hours before aborting.
- After aborting the process and re-running, I receive the following error:

```
/home/username/dev/will-it-miss/src/index.css:undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function
at LazyResult.run (/home/username/dev/will-it-miss/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:288:14)
at LazyResult.asyncTick (/home/username/dev/will-it-miss/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:212:26)
at /home/username/dev/will-it-miss/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:254:14
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at LazyResult.async (/home/username/dev/will-it-miss/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:250:23)
at LazyResult.then (/home/username/dev/will-it-miss/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:131:17)
```

Being new to development I haven't had much luck in troubleshooting this error but these are the actions taken so far:

- Set `index.js script` type to module and updated SVG paths as suggested in this thread on the [MDN Discourse forum](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/help-needed-with-introducing-a-complete-toolchain/88832/).
- Replaced the postcss specific nested selectors from index.css with regular selectors
- Reverted the project version of postcss to a previous build
- Deleted and rebuilt the project from scratch 5~ times and get the same results (Stuck `building scheduler-tracing.development.js`, abort process, re-run and error relating to index.css outlined above.

Another user reported the same error I have as shown in the linked forum thread. if there is any other info that could be useful in troubleshooting this error, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Run the following command to install a compatible version of
   postcss-preset-env: `npm install --save-dev postcss-preset-env@6.7.0`
2. Add a single file called .postcssrc.json (if it is not already there; this replaces the .postcssrc file) to the root of your project
   directory.
3. Add the following contents to the new file, which will automagically
   give us full access to the latest CSS features:

   `{ "plugins": { "postcss-preset-env": { "stage": 0 } } }`
4. Run the `npx parcel index.html` command again.

References:

Github, Inc. Issue with "Introducing a complete toolchain": fails to build; problem with postcss-preset-env versions #12495. https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/12495#issuecomment-1025004164. (Accessed 20 July, 2022).